# Proof of an identity with binomials and polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Given $S=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}{(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}}P_k(i)$ where $P_k(i)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $i$.  I have to prove that $S=0$ for $n>k$. How can I do that?

Comment: First show that $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} i^k=0$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833276/if-px-is-any-polynomial-of-degree-less-than-n-show-that-sum-j-0n-1/3833675#3833675

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summation of series involving binomial coefficients and polynomial of degree at most n-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179612/summation-of-series-involving-binomial-coefficients-and-polynomial-of-degree-at)

Comment: yes now i see that my question is duplicated! Many thanks!